# Don't send data from js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem.

Send from Chrome console. Work.

```
var composeData = {viewer_user_id: 37247, subject: '321', message: '32131', dialog_id: null};
Node.socket.emit('composeMessage', composeData);
```

Send from some .js file. Don't work.

```
    composeMessage: function()
    {
            var dialog_id = ($('#dialog_id').val() == '') ? null : $('#dialog_id').val();
            var to_id = $('#to_id').val();

            if (to_id)
            {
                    var composeData = {viewer_user_id: to_id, subject: $('#subject').val(), message: $('#message').val(), dialog_id: dialog_id};
                    Node.socket.emit('composeMessage', composeData);
            } else
            {
                    $('.messages').notification('empty addressee data', 'error', uniqueid(6));
            }
    }
```

The problem is that the data is written to MongoDB, in the first case - everything is OK, the other - nothing happens, even no errors.

*One gets the feeling that the onClick event adds to the object of some other unseen data.*

**Node.js app**

index.js:

```
socket.on('composeMessage', function(clientData) {
    console.log(arguments); // OK!
    IM.testInsert(clientData);
});
```

IM.js:

```
testInsert: function(clientData) {
    console.log(clientData); // OK!
    mongo_db.collection('test').insert(clientData, function() {
        console.log(arguments); // Not Working if send data from JS file (client), but work if send data from chrome dev-tool
    });
}
```

That looked out over WebSocket. In the first case (line 1) I send data via the Chrome Dev-tools, in the second case (line 3) through the event onClick. As you can see, the data are identical.

[image]

Comment: If you do `console.log(composeData)` right before you send it in the script, is it formated correctly there compared to when you send it from the console?

Comment: What data is received in your Node.JS code?

Comment: @Alexander The data coming in on node.js app, in both cases - the same. Check all. Even the type of the object. But after sending data through a web-based application - are not written to the database.

Comment: @RomanGorbatko It sounds like the problem is in the function that writes the data to the database then, could you please post the code where you are doing that? And have you tried using the log statement in that function to see if everything seems correct there too?

Comment: @Alexander Look change my post. P.S. I don't think the problem is on the side of the node.

Comment: @RomanGorbatko Could it be that when you run `.val()` there is a mismatch between a string and a number? (As the `.val()` function can [return both](http://api.jquery.com/val/).) Try sending the request in the exact same way, i.e. hardcode the values in your js function as well and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Alexander It did not help. Even if I send the static data, such as `{a: 123}` - the same thing happens.

Comment: @RomanGorbatko What happens if you run your `composeMessage` function from the Chrome console, does that work?

Comment: @Alexander Yes. In That's the "mysticism" of this situation :)

Comment: @RomanGorbatko Could you please post the code from where it doesn't work? If the function in itself works then where it's called seems to be the issue.

Comment: @Alexander `'<button class="button" onclick="IM.composeMessage();">'`

Comment: isn't there an `error` callback you can check? something like `mongo_db.collection('test').insert(clientData, function(err) {`

Comment: @fusio No, I can not declare variables for the arguments (in your case `err`).

Comment: oh, well, if nothing else works and it is a database related problem, you could try switching to [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).. not sure it will help, but who knows?

Comment: @fusio Yes, I think it's worth a try. Soon accomplish your goal.

Comment: @fusio Yes! With `Mongoose` things work. I can imagine that this is a bug `Mongoskin`?

Comment: @RomanGorbatko possible, although I cannot imagine what did cause it. you could try posting a new Issue in their GitHub :) glad it worked out with mongoose.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35755/discussion-between-romangorbatko-and-fusio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I can post my suggestion as answer, even though the actual bug is still unclear.

It appear to be a Mongoskin related problem, switching to Mongoose solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hm ... I'm thinking for two things:

a) Try removing property by property. Doing this you will find out which one is problematic. I'm interested in *dialog_id* particularly

b) Change *viewer_user_id: to_id* to

```
viewer_user_id: parseInt(to_id)
```

Comment: a) `{a: 123}` - don't work. b) Already tried. It did not work.